# Why does Debian squeeze forget its static IP address and seek a DHCP lease?

Tags: networking, debian, dhcp, debian-squeeze

Hi have a Debian Squeeze box with eth0 and eth1.

In /etc/network/interfaces is:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
 address 10.1.2.208
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 10.1.2.1
```

But every 24 hours, eth1 loses its statically-assigned IP address, and fetches one from DHCP instead!  Manually doing:

```
# ifup eth1 && ifdown eth1
```

puts it back to how it should be.

But why does it spontaneously break in the first place?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is `dhcpcd`/`dhclient` still running? It will refresh its DHCP address on the interface if you don't kill it.

Also, did you configure Network Manager? That'll override the `interfaces` file. Get rid of it if you're not using it.

Comment: Change 'dhcpcd' to 'dhclient' above, and I'll mark this answer as correct.  It seems that if you edit /etc/networking/interfaces so that eth1 is now 'static' instead of 'dhcp', then an 'ifdown eth1 && ifup eth1' **won't kill the dhclient instance** which ifupdown started initially.  Kill it manually, and it stays away when you ifdown/ifup.

Comment: Exactly. It would have worked if you had run `ifdown`, THEN edited to change the method to `static`, THEN run `ifup`. In your case, `ifdown` had no idea that `dhclient` needed to be killed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 10.1.2.208
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 10.1.2.1
  hwaddress ether mac_address_of_the_network_card_here
```

For example:

```
...
  hwaddress ether 00:00:5e:00:53:b2
```

Comment: How does this improve on accepted answer?

Comment: It is for remember myself. ;)